# C1083: Cannot open include file: duckx/duckx.hpp: No such file or directory,

Tags: c++, cmake, include, visual-studio-2022, lib

Cannot find files <duckx/duckx.hpp>
in doc:

#include <duckx/duckx.hpp>

Did it as in the instructions.

VS 2022, Cmake.
CmakeLists.txt

```
project ("Document")
set(Incl_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Include")
add_subdirectory("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Include/Duckx-Master/")
find_package(duckx)
add_executable (Document Document.cpp Document.h)
target_link_libraries(Document PRIVATE duckx::duckx)
```

#include <duckx/duckx.hpp> that version include isnt work.
Try to write "../Include/Duckx-Master/include/duckx.hpp" Thats is right path.
But appears new problems with same errors
C1083: Cannot open include file constants.hpp: No such file or directory.
That lib using in duckx.hpp